# v-model variable return whole select instead of its value

Tags: vue.js

I want to get value from select tag. So I bind a variable with v-model like below.

HTML:

```
<div id="action_panel">
    <select id="work_type" v-model="type">
        <option value="" disabled selected></option>
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
    </select>
<div>
```

JS:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#action_panel',
    data: {},
    methods: {
        addWorks: function(emp_id) {
            console.log(type);
        }
    }
});
```

console.log() returns the whole html entity of select tag.

I got no clues on [vue.js doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Select).

Answer (score 2):

The `type` variable is never declared. You should declare it as data of your application before using it.

https://jsfiddle.net/gurghet/mwy5uLb4/

Comment: ...also, you should refer to it as `this.type` inside methods.